# Android playing song during call

Tags: android, call, audio-player

I am trying to build an application which plays a song during call. It is working fine when calling someone. But it is unable to play the song while continuing with the call.
I have put the mp3 file in the assets folder. Here is my code:

```
if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
    // active
    //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("la.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        mp.prepare();
        mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It is working fine to call" ?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this as calling the playAudio() before calling the callIntent-

```
public void playAudio() {
    try {
        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            Log.d("Playing the audio", "");
            m.stop();
            m.release();
            m = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        m.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("test.mp3");
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        m.prepare();
        m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m.setLooping(true);
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopAudio() {
    if (m.isPlaying()) {
        Log.d("stop the audio", "");
        m.stop();
        m.release();
        m = new MediaPlayer();
    }

}

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            //Hangup
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                stopAudio();
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                break;
            //Outgoing
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                break;
            //Incoming
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                break;
        }
    }
}
```